# Apollo Client what are active queries?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

#### My Setup

- Typescript React App
- Backend GraphQL API
- Apollo Client
- Inspecting with Apollo Client Devtools Extension

#### My question

- What are active queries? The Apollo Docs talks about active queries a lot but I am struggling to get an actual definition.
- I understood that an active query is basically a link from your component state to the overall global state of the Apollo Client cache. Is this correct?
- Why do I see 2 queries being listed when I only have one query in my react component (see screen recording). For example in my events pages I call on query `listEvents` but then I see that query appear twice in my active queries when I load the page. Is seems to be the same for any new query.
- Why do my active queries keep increasing when I am just navigating back and forth between the same pages and fetching the same data. Based on my understanding, I would expect the number of active queries not to increase in this case as I am not introducing and new queries.
- I am worried that there is some issue in my setup leading to new active queries being created instead of 'recycling' existing ones. Am I right? And if so how can I debug/fix this?

[image: Active Queries Screen Recording]

Thanks,

Comment: I have exactly the same questions and issues, did you manage to sort this out?

Comment: Nope I didn't :(

Comment: Did you find the answer on your question?

Answer (score 3):

Active queries are queries running in mounted components so Apollo knows what query result to update when cache is updated. If you're sure you're not running those queries at the same time, you can check your routing library to see if they don't keep your last page in cache.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue and in my instance (react 18.2.0 & apollo-client 3.8.6) it was due to react StrictMode.

Somebody has opened a ticket for it [on GitHub](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9903). Fortunately, it does not affect production builds as StrictMode is development only.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apollo Client documentation (updated in [late 2023](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/11357)):

> Active queries are those used by components on the current page.
>
> -- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetching-queries

And another description:

> An "active" query is one that has observers and a `fetchPolicy` other than "standby" or "cache-only".
>
> -- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient#getObservableQueries

Also, in an official forum post by Apollo staff:

> any query that’s part of a rendered component, regardless of whether the query is currently executing.
>
> -- https://community.apollographql.com/t/apollo-client-active-query-definition/2420/2